# Stop selection of page elements when link is clicked

Tags: css, select, scrollable, textselection

I'm writing a page containing a javascript scrollable element using the jQuery Tools Scrollble plug in. You can view my page here: idiots.mrtriangle.me

When you click on the Gallery tab, access a gallery and click the 'scroll buttons', on second click it highlights the entire page, which is quite annoying. I'm not sure why it's doing this, is there any way to remove this selection?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]I think your asking about the problem which is in my image. And this is the solution for this problem.

```
<a class="next browse right"></a>
```

Your using the above element for that scroller. just set the href attribute like this.

```
<a class="next browse right" href="javascript:;"></a>
```

i this this will help U.

If you want to sent dynamically set like this in jquery

$('.next browse right').attr('href','javascript:;');

Comment: Ah,forgot the href. Idiot. Thanks :)

Comment: I forgot the href att on my links. I was calling myself an idiot :P. Thanks for your help.